# Home button missing in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, home-button

I can't see the home button (icon) in the `ActionBar` when I create a completely new project in eclipse (`Activity` with `ActionBar` extends android support v7 app `ActionBarActivity`). No changes were made in the project. I'm using the new Android 5.0 sdk.

There is also no change when I set for instance

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
```

Generated manifest, ic_launcher is in the correct directory:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[image]

Comment: Be sure to extend ActionBarActivity

Comment: Yes I did it => public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the eclipse and android sdk again. Now it works.